# convert initializer_list<T> to initializer_list<vector<T>> at compile time

Tags: c++, initializer-list, constexpr

I have a class constructor that accepts an

```
initializer_list<T>
```

this constructor has to run the parent class constructor that accepts an

```
initializer_list<vector<T>>.
```

so I have to convert the initializer list to an 2d initializer list.

```
{1, 2, 3, 4} to { {1}, {2}, {3}, {4} }
```

EDIT:

I have a class constructor that accepts an

```
initializer_list<T>
```

this constructor has to run the parent class constructor that accepts an

```
initializer_list<array<T, 1>>.
```

so I have to convert the initializer list to an 2d initializer list.

```
{1, 2, 3, 4} to { {1}, {2}, {3}, {4} }
```

Comment: Reply to answers by clicking the "add a comment" button under them; don't make edits that have nothing to do with the question you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below you can find a complete example if you are still having troubles with mixing `<typename T>` from class' declaration with `<typename... Args>` pack within constructor:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <utility>
#include <initializer_list>

template <typename T>
class A
{
public:
    A(std::initializer_list<std::array<T, 1>> i);

    virtual ~A() = default;
};

template <typename T>
A<T>::A(std::initializer_list<std::array<T, 1>> i)
{
    std::cout << i.size() << std::endl;
}

template <typename T>
class B : public A<T>
{
public:
    template <typename... Args>
    B(Args&&... args);
};

template <typename T>
template <typename... Args>
B<T>::B(Args&&... args) : A<T>{std::array<T, 1>{std::forward<Args>(args)}...}
{

}

int main()
{
    B<int> b{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 };
    return 0;
}
```

[Live demo link.](http://ideone.com/StG4RT)

Answer (score 3):

Why not have your child class take parameter pack and forward it off to the parent constructor?

```c++
struct Parent
{
    template<typename T>
    Parent(std::initializer_list<std::array<T, 1>>) { }

    virtual ~Parent() = default;
};

struct Child : Parent
{
    template<class... Args>
    Child(Args&&... args) : Parent{{{args}...}} { }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

`std::initializer_list<T>` is an odd hybrid: to create one, you'll need to statically know its size and content but once you get handed one, you can't statically determine its content! Put differently, I don't think you can create an `std::initializer_list<std::vector<T>>` from an `std::initializer_list<T>`.

What you *can* do is to take a variadic argument list, possibly constraint to have all the same type and the type being integral, and construct an `std::initializer_list<std::vector<T>>` from that:

```
template <typename T>
void g(std::initializer_list<T> list) { ... }

template <typename... T>
void f(T... args) {
    g({ std::array<T, 1>(args)... });
}
```